# Deployment of two programs that communicate between them

Tags: c++, python, deployment, sockets

On windows, I have done one client in c++ and one server in python. In order to make the program work, I need first to run the server (in one terminal), and then I can run the client.

I am trying to deploy the project and create an installer out of the process. The thing is that I don't know how to run the server always before when launching the app. I don't know if I need to create an installer for the server and an installer for the client, and when executing the client has a script to run the server before (I don't one to ship the python source code, I would need to compile it or do something in order to avoid this).

One solution that I see feasible is to embed the python code as a DLL library and launch the server from the client (loading the DLL somehow). I don't know if that would work as I never did something similar. Also, I don't know if that's good as I am sending requests and sending responses from the server (it seems odd to me to call the server from the client).

The software is a desktop application. If it helps I am using ZMQ to do the communication.

How this client-server relationship should be done?

Thank you in advance,
Cheers.

Comment: You always want to run client and server on the same machine, right? So why not check inside the client if the server process is running before establishing any C/S communication, and if not, just start the server process?

Comment: Which of ZeroMQ's sockets are you using?   If the client uses a socket with reliability built-in (e.g. `REQ` or `DEALER`) then it shouldn't matter whether the server has already started or whether it starts a little later.

Comment: Furthermore, it sounds as if the process you're describing as a 'server' in this scenario is really the client, at least from a communication perspective.

Comment: @DocBrown Yes, I always want to run the client and the server on the same machine. I could check this, and I agree. My issue then, it's how to avoid distributing the python packages and scripts, and how to call the binary out of it. The user does not need to know about this.

Comment: @BenCottrell Yes, you could say that. The client is sending an image from the GUI (c++ client) then the python server is doing some ML and stuff on that image and giving it back to the client. My issue is to make the server run when the user selects the image. I don't want to call the python interpreter from the GUI. Should I call another binary to run from the client? What's the best practice for this? This is my question. How to run the client and be sure that the server is running.

Comment: @BenCottrell Also, to not distribute the python scripts to the client. I can call them from the Python C API but they are not a library or anything at the moment that I could distribute in order to avoid the user having the python scripts source code.

Comment: @thecatbehindthemask: Python deployment on Windows is something which can be easily googled. Google took me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646326/how-to-deploy-python-to-windows-users) in a few seconds. If that does not help, tell us why.

Comment: Hi @DocBrown that's not my issue. My issue is calling the python DLL which is already deployed from the client to ensure that the python server is running. I can use pyInstaller to create the exe on windows.

Comment: Can't your client simply try to connect to the server, and if the connection fails, it knows it has to start the server? Since you want to install both one the same machine, a response should come quickly, so you can keep the timeouts quite short. And forget about "a DLL", when you wrote your Python server as a script for CPython, it will be executed by the Python bytecode interpreter in the background, regardless how you package it.

Comment: @DocBrown If I execute the python script with CPython, it will be executed in bytecode, yes, but If I am correct the python script source code would be accessible to the user, and I don't want that.

Comment: That's a very different problem than "launch the server from the client" or "create an installer", it seems you are mixing some things up here. But FWIW, your best bet is probably to use Cython, as described [here at the Pyinstaller web site](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#hiding-the-source-code).

Comment: @DocBrown Thank you, I will have a look.